# Conditional probability red balls

Tags: probability

One box contains four black balls and five red balls.
Two balls are pulled out without putting them back.

What is the probability that the second ball is red if the first ball was black.

I'm not sure if my solution is correct:

All possible events $ \Omega:=\{(\text{red},\text{red}),(\text{red},\text{black}),(\text{black},\text{red}),(\text{black},\text{black})\} $

Event A := "Second ball is red." $ :=\{(\text{red},\text{red}),(\text{black},\text{red})\} $

Event B := "First ball is black." $ :=\{(\text{black},\text{red}),(\text{black},\text{black})\} $

Probabilitytree:
[image]

Then I have $ A\cap B=\{(\text{black},\text{red})\} $ and

$ P_B(A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{\frac{4}{9}\cdot \frac{5}{8}}{\frac{4}{9}\cdot \frac{5}{8}+\frac{4}{9}\cdot \frac{3}{8}}=\frac{5}{8} $

Comment: "For" black balls or "four" black balls??

Comment: Of course "four". It was just a typo. I corrected it. Thank you!

Comment: So you type "*What is the probability that the second ball is black if the first ball was*  **$\color{red}{\text{red}}$**." and condition w.r.t. the event $B$ which is the first ball being **black**? Please take time and explain.

Comment: Sorry, it was annother typo. I corrected it.

Comment: No problem. (But the downvoter may consider it still...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct but overly worked.

You can read the answer off the tree.  It is the probability on the second branch off the first root.  You calculated this as $5/8$ , being the probability for drawing one among the five red balls when selecting from the eight balls remaining after removing a red ball.

That was all you needed to do!

There was no need to fill out the rest of the tree to use the definition for conditional probability.

---

You used the value you *already had* for $\mathsf P(A\mid B)$ to calculate $\mathsf P(A\mid B)$.

$$\color{blue}{\mathsf P(A\mid B)}=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B)~\color{blue}{\mathsf P(A\mid B)}}{\mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(A^\complement\mid B)+\mathsf P(B)~\color{blue}{\mathsf P(A\mid B)}}$$

Comment: Wow thanks! Especially the concepts in probability are for me quite confusing. I do a refresh noticing I used not a nice notation few years ago and having teachers who jumped too fast in this field which led to more confusions in probability. So I do restart maybe with some overkilled (or unneeded/unnecessary) ways. But this helps me a lot to come in more clear. Bayes'Rule would be the next step.

Answer (score 1):

The first ball was black. So there remain

- five $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ balls, and
- three **black** balls.

The probability to extract a **red** ball is now $\displaystyle\frac{\bf 5}{\bf 5 +\bf 3}=\frac 58$.

In your picture, it is the $5/8$ marked after the first branching to black, going into the red ball.

Comment: I really don't know what you are meaning. Why was the first ball red?

Comment: Dan just answered the wrong question.  You were correct.  Still, you did not need to fill out the tree and use Bayes' Rule, since you already calculated the answer on the tree.

Comment: My answer was typed in one minute short before going to bed after a hard days job, it is good possible that there were some errors. The answer was edited, so that i do not understand it any more. Again: "*One box contains four* (initially "for" in the OP) *black balls and five red balls. Two balls are pulled out without putting them back.*" Then we extract a first ball. And compute some conditional probability knowing this **first ball is red**. As in "<<What is the probability that the second ball is black if **the first ball was red** .>>" OK, then there remain 4+4. Got language daltonisms.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I still have my problems with the edit, so at the beginning we had $5$ red + $4$ black. We compute a conditional probability, conditioning w.r.t. the fact that the first ball is red, isn't it so?